# Can only one unique constraint be applied on the column while others are defined?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Let's say we have to keep people votes, which can be either from users or guests:

```
CREATE TABLE votes (
  to_user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  from_user_id INT UNSIGNED,
  from_ip_address INT UNSIGNED
)
```

For user votes we want to apply a unique constraint `(to_user_id, from_user_id)` and for guest a constraint `(to_user_id, from_ip_address)`.

There is no combination of unique indexes, which are applied at the same time, that would not broke any of these: the uniqueness of votes and the ability of different users with the same ip address to vote.

Is there any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Votes (
    VoteId int unsigned primary key,
    UserId int unsigned not null,
    IpAddress int unisgned,
    Which enum('from', 'to'),
    constraint unq_Votes_UserId_IpAddress_Which unique (UserId, IpAddress, Which)
);
```

Note that I added a primary key, which is handy for foreign key references, identifying a single row, and maintaining the ordering of inserts.

Comment: And how with this structure we understand which user voted for which?

Comment: @alain_morel . . . You have to look at the `which` column to determine the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've found an acceptable solution:

```
CREATE TABLE votes (
  vote_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  to_user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  from_user_id INT UNSIGNED,
  from_user_ip INT UNSIGNED,
  from_guest_ip INT UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (vote_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (to_user_id, from_user_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (to_user_id, from_guest_ip)
);

INSERT INTO votes (to_user_id, from_user_id, from_user_ip) VALUES (1, 2, 255), (1, 3, 255);
INSERT INTO votes (to_user_id, from_guest_ip) VALUES (1, 255);
```